# common lisp: read list into list

Tags: common-lisp

It might seem simple, but I can't get it to work. I simply need to read a file where the contents are just one big list

```
(a b c d)
```

. . . as is . . . into a list in my program. I have

```
(let ((ardplst nil))     
...
(with-open-file (in ardpfile :direction :input :if-does-not-exist nil)
    (when in
      (read-sequence ardplst in))      
        (format t "~a" ardplst))
```

But it's not working. I get NIL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `:if-does-not-exist nil` suggests to me that `ardpfile` doesn't refer to what you intend it to. Did you use a full path?

Comment: That's not it. Full path just gets the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does [`read-sequence`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_seq.htm) do? It reads some [*elements*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_e.htm#element) from the stream, typically *characters* (but it depends on the element-type of the stream) and destructively insert them into the input sequence. So, you would collect characters `#\(`, then `#\a`, then `#\Space`, then `#\b`, etc. *However*, reading stops as soon as you reach the end of your sequence: with your empty list, that means *immediately* (you are supposed to pass a buffer, e.g. a vector). In you case, `read-sequence` returns 0.

The reason you get `nil` is because your last expression is `format`, which in the above code outputs to the standard output (because of `t`) and returns `nil`. You could have used [`print`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm), which returns the printed object.

I don't understand why you are explicitely using `:if-does-not-exist nil`. Are you sure you want to silently skip the task if the file cannot be opened? What if the list you read is empty? You should probably let an error be signaled in case the file is not found.

I would use `read` while disabling read-time evaluation:

```
(with-open-file (in my-file)
   (let* ((*read-eval* nil)
          (list (read in)))
     (prog1 list
       (check-type list list))))
```

Note that the default `:direction` is `:input`. In my opinion it does not hurt to omit this argument here, though sometimes it can be more readable to write it explicitely.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but the code doesn't seem to work. Parens problems and `(check-type list list)` gives issues. What is `(list (read in))` doing?

Comment: @147pm Sorry, I modified the code directly here without testing. As you might have guessed with the updated version, `(list (read in))` is a binding: the variable `list` holds the form read from the stream.

Comment: @147pm Should be okay now, I should go to sleep ;-)